# Error reserving memory in the heap c++

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
#include<cstring>



struct stringy
{
    char * str;
    int ct;
};

void set(stringy & stringa, char ar[]);
void show(stringy & stringa);

int main()
{
    stringy beany;
    char testing[] = "Reality isn't what is used to be.";

    set(beany, testing);
    show(beany);

    return 0;
}

void set(stringy & stringa, char * ar)
{
    char * ps = new char[strlen(ar) + 1];
    stringa.str = ps;
    strcpy(ar,ps);
    cout << strlen(stringa.str);
    stringa.ct++;
    delete [] ps;

}

void show(stringy & stringa)
{
    for(int i = 0; stringa.str[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        cout << stringa.str[i];
    }
}
```

This is my code. It's part of an exercise. I was given the body of the main function as asked to write functions that did the requested task.

locates space to hold copy of testing, 
sets str member of beany to point to the
new block, copies testing to new block,
and sets ct member of beany

My issue is with the set function. I feel as though i have satisfied the criteria, the strlen is there because i am trying to figure out what is going on... it returns 0. then the program exits.

Comment: You do this: `stringa.str = ps;`.  Then you do this: `delete [] ps;`  Ask yourself "why did I do this?"

Comment: I was under the assumption that every time new is used you have to free the memory.  I see now that it renders the function pointless...

Comment: After the function terminates, what happens to that reserved memory?

Comment: Look at your `show` function.  You are attempting to print `stringa.str`.  How can you print this when just before in `set`, you deallocated the memory `stringa.str` was pointing to?  You deallocated the memory prematurely -- that's the point of my first comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of problems with this code, among which:

```
strcpy(ar, ps);
```

This copies `ps` to `ar`, not the other way around.  You want:

```
strcpy(ps, ar);
```

This error would have been detected by the compiler if the `const` qualifier were used as it should have been.

Additionally, the `delete[] ps` at the end of `set()` should not be there.

Finally, I'm not sure what the purpose of the `ct` field is, so I can't tell you what it should be, but incrementing an uninitialized field is certainly wrong.